# Pass arguments to python application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, terminal, argparse

I have a Python3 application and I want to pass it some arguments using Ubuntu 18.04 terminal:

```
python3 app/app.py -af app/annotation_file.json -em app/model/ -output_dir app/new_model/ -n_iter 100
```

I am trying to do this using argparse:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from argparse import ArgumentParser

    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-af", "--annotation_file",
                        dest="main", default=None,
                        help="Path to annotated file")
    parser.add_argument("-em", "--existing_model_path",
                        dest="main", default=None,
                        help="Retrain existing model or train from scratch")
    parser.add_argument("-output_dir", "--output_dir_to_save_model",
                        dest="main", default="/app/model",
                        help="Path to save newly generated NER model")
    parser.add_argument("-n_iter", "--num_iter",
                        dest="main", default=100,
                        help="Number of iterations to train the model")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
    main(args)
```

Output:

```
Namespace(main='100')
Namespace(main='100')
```

But I am not getting the output.
How can I pass all the above named arguments to my `main()` function?

Comment: There's no special `main` in python

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have a main() function in my code.
I want to pass it the arguments from the terminal.

Comment: Then show that.

Comment: Keep in mind that `dest` is the variable in the namespace that each option ends up in. I don't know why you called them all `main`. Perhaps delete the `dest='main'` portions?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I mean that if my main() function just prints these arguments (for example) how can I pass all the named arguments to the function?

I mean that args will be something like a dictionary: ```{"af": "app/annotations.json", "n_iter": 100 ... }```

Comment: Please show an MCVE. I've basically answered your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so, you're passing arguments to the function all right, but as each one of your parser lines saves the input data to:

```
dest="main"
```

your main variable gets overwritten for every new parser.add_argument line.

If your main() function takes four arguments, change each parser.add_argument() line's dest="" line to point to a different variable, then, call your main() function with:

```
main(args.arg1, args.arg2, args.arg3, args.arg4)
```

where arg-n is each of your newly created different variables.

Example, given your code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from argparse import ArgumentParser

    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-af", "--annotation_file",
                        dest="arg1", default=None,
                        help="Path to annotated file")
    parser.add_argument("-em", "--existing_model_path",
                        dest="arg2", default=None,
                        help="Retrain existing model or train from scratch")
    parser.add_argument("-output_dir", "--output_dir_to_save_model",
                        dest="arg3", default="/app/model",
                        help="Path to save newly generated NER model")
    parser.add_argument("-n_iter", "--num_iter",
                        dest="arg4", default=100,
                        help="Number of iterations to train the model")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
    main(args.arg1, args.arg2, args.arg3, args.arg4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would clean up your parser definition (I dropped the `dest`, and fixed the short option flags):

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-a", "--af", "--annotation_file",
                    help="Path to annotated file")
parser.add_argument("-e", "--em", "--existing_model_path",
                    help="Retrain existing model or train from scratch")
parser.add_argument(+-o", "--output_dir", "--output_dir_to_save_model",
                    default="/app/model",
                    help="Path to save newly generated NER model")
parser.add_argument("-n", "--n_iter", "--num_iter",
                    default=100,
                    help="Number of iterations to train the model")

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Now you will see all 4 arguments in the `namespace`, and can access they by name

```
args.n_iter
args.output_dir
```

Normally the `dest` is taken from one of the double dash flags.  The fact that you will eventually pass `args` to `main()` is of no relevance to `argparse`.  You messed up your parser by supplying the same `dest` to all 4 arguments, with the result that you only see the value for one.

As documented, you can easily get a dictionary version with

```
vars(args)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest

> For optional argument actions, the value of dest is normally inferred from the option strings. ArgumentParser generates the value of dest by taking the first long option string and stripping away the initial -- string. If no long option strings were supplied, dest will be derived from the first short option string by stripping the initial - character.